# Сборка .deb пакетов

Tags: debian

Сделал небольшую вещицу. Теперь хотелось бы собрать это всё в .deb пакет. Вообщем, что для сборки использовать проще всего? Ещё хотелось бы прилепить это в скрытую папку домашнего каталога. Подскажите что заюзать, а там я и сам погугляшу.

Существует статья на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/78094/ (Искренне извиняюсь за ссылку на левый сайт) но там так и не указано, как запихнуть это в домашний каталог пользователя. Это меня и поставило в тупик. Не знаю, как обозвать папку.

Comment: в момент инсталяции пакета обычно ни чего не устанавливают в $HOME, потому-что пакет устанавливается из-под рута всегда. А в $HOME писать нужно от самой программы а не установочными скриптами. директории в linux используются так:

 * /usr/bin/ - запускаемые
 * /usr/share/progname/ - всякие картинки и прочее 
 * /usr/lib/ - библиотеки
 * /usr/share/doc/progname/  -документация
 * /opt/progname/ - для ленивых придурков из оракла, которые не могут нормальный пакет собрать.

Comment: для начального скелета можно использовать dh-make

Answer (score 1):

Думая не очень хорошая идея ставить программу из deb пакета в home пользователя. Хотя у нас на работе была похожая задача, я выкрутился так, создал tar.gz с программой и написал для распаковки скрипт который ставит недостающие пакеты (потребуется пароль root'a), затем с нашего сервера скачивает архив с программой и распаковывает в домашнею директорию пользователя, добавляется путь к программе в переменную PATH.